# cannot be changed from type [geo_point] to xxx

Tags: go, elasticsearch

The mapping type is geo_point, what type should I use in golang

### my struct :

[image]

### my code :

[image]

### result message:

```
[400 Bad Request] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [localhost] cannot be changed from type [geo_point] to [float]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [localhost] cannot be changed from type [geo_point] to [float]"},"status":400}
```

Comment: my use struct mode create doc

Comment: better you check the type of each value and then u convert it after u know the kind of type ,

Comment: My definition in mapping is localhost:{type:geo_point}, I don’t know how to create doc in go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the query you are running I can imagine you are not passing the right format for geo_point field type.

According to the docs you need to pass `lat` and `lon` properties object.

**Mappings**

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Ingesting data**

```
PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{
  "text": "Geo-point as an object",
  "location": { 
    "lat": 41.12,
    "lon": -71.34
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
GET /my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "200km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 40,
            "lon": -70
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please attach your current query if you need more help

Comment: I have modified my post, please check